# two parameters to jquery function

Tags: jquery

In my page I have two divs called context and translation and in test1.php I get two strings one is for context the other is for translation areas. I have written as follows but I can not write the values into the two divs, is there a way to that?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "test1.php",

}).done(function( msg1, msg2 ) {
document.getElementById("context").innerHTML=msg1;
document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML=msg2;

});
```

Comment: if you use jQuery this -  document.getElementById("context").innerHTML=msg1; could be transformed to  - $('#context').html(msg1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `.done()` is not going to have your two variables `msg1` and `msg2` as it's parameters.

You can either use a traditional jQuery ajax success handler and then get the single response argument out of it or if you want to use deferred syntax, you can use a .success() method which will likewise get the same single response argument from which you would have to retrieve both msg1 and msg2.

Here's [one article](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/) with an example using `.success(fn)` instead of `.done(fn)`.

You can see [here](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) that `.done(fn)` doesn't pass the result of the ajax call to the callback like your code is expecting.

So, I think you want something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "test1.php",
  success: function(response) {
       // parse your msg1 and msg2 values out of the response here
       // How you do that depends upon what the response to the POST is
       document.getElementById("context").innerHTML=msg1;
       document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML=msg2;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you use something like

```
$('#context').html(msg1);
$('#translation').html(msg2);
```

using the jquery.